# imap_tools Taking Long Time to Scrape Links from Emails

Tags: python, imap, imap-tools

I am using imap_tools to get links from emails. The emails are very small with very little text, graphics, etc. There are also not many, around 20-40 spread through the day.

When a new email arrives it takes between 10 and 25 seconds to scrape the link. This seems very long. I would have expected it to be less than 2 seconds and speed is important.

Nb. it is a shared mailbox and I cannot simply fetch unseeen emails because often other users will have opened emails before the scraper gets to them.

Can anyone see what the issue is?

```
import pandas as pd
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND
import re, time, datetime, os
from config import email, password

uids = []
yahooSmtpServer = "imap.mail.yahoo.com"
data = {
    'today': str(datetime.datetime.today()).split(' ')[0],
    'uids': []
    }
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            client = MailBox(yahooSmtpServer).login(email, password, 'INBOX')
            try:
                if not data['today'] == str(datetime.datetime.today()).split(' ')[0]:
                    data['today'] = str(datetime.datetime.today()).split(' ')[0]
                    data['uids'] = []
                ds = str(datetime.datetime.today()).split(' ')[0].split('-')
                msgs = client.fetch(AND(date_gte=datetime.date.today()))
                for msg in msgs:
                    links = []
                    if str(datetime.datetime.today()).split(' ')[0] == str(msg.date).split(' ')[0] and not msg.uid in data['uids']:
                        mail = msg.html
                        if 'order' in mail and not 'cancel' in mail:
                            for i in re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', mail):
                                if 'pick' in i:
                                    link = i.replace('"', "")
                                    link = link.replace('<', '>').split('>')[0]
                                    print(link)
                                    links.append(link)
                                    break
                        data['uids'].append(msg.uid)
                        scr_links = pd.DataFrame({'Links': links})
                        scr_links.to_csv('Links.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
                        time.sleep(0.5)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                pass
            client.logout()
            time.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('sleeping for 5 sec')
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Did you try profiling it to see where the "slow" part(s) are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is email server throttle timeout.

Try to see IMAP IDLE.

since 0.51.0 imap_tools has IDLE support:

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools/releases/tag/v0.51.0

Comment: Hi Vladimir, do you mean yahoo is limiting my fetch request frequency? Thanks

Comment: @Andy, I think yes, but you should ask yahoo.